# What is the correct code for Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I am trying to follow a tutorial, and the instructor had me copy his code seen below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>

<title>Bootstrap Practise</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

</head>
<body>
<div class="Container">

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-1 bg-warning">
      1
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-1 bg-info">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 bg-danger">
      3
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 bg-success">
      4
    </div>
    <div class= "col-lg-1 bg-warning">
      5
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 bg-info">
      6
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 bg-danger">
      7
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 bg-success">
      8
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 bg-warning">
      9
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 bg-info">
      10
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 bg-danger">
      11
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 bg-success">
      12
    </div>


</div>

</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">        </script>


<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

I have duplicated the instructors code exactly, and when he runs it he gets 12 columns in a container, with white space on each side. When I run it, I get 12 rows that take up the entire screen and do not stack when I reduce the screen size.

Comment: I do not see a third line. Also, would be helpful if you put in the code that is not working (if you want help with that part of your question).

Comment: `bootstrap.min.css` is the core Bootstrap CSS (required to use Bootstrap).  `bootstrap-theme.min.css` is an optional theme for styling

Comment: That code works for me. My guess is that you are not loading the bootstrap stylesheets correctly. Check your developer console and see if there is an error loading those files.

Comment: Thank you for your help. @Josh F    I have edited my question to try and make it more specific to the problem I am having, and I also included all of the code I am using. I hope someone can offer some further assistance, as this problem is really starting to get to me.

Comment: The code creates columns when the browser is wide enough, not when you *reduce* the size.  Basically, if you have a small form factor device (mobile, tablet), you get a bunch of rows, but if you have a desktop, you get the columns.  Try **increasing** the size of the browser screen and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

You have a mistake in your code.

Replace `class="Container"`  by  `class="container"`

Comment: Man you are good. I have been trying to fix that for days. Drinks are on me.  I now have a container, ( small c ) with white space on each side.  Now I just need to figure out why I don´t have 12 columns on my desktop like the tutor does. My browser is 1094 px wide, and at full width, I still get 12 rows. However if I run it in Firefox, in Responsive Design M, and increase the size to 1280 I get the 12 columns but with a horizontal scroll.  Come on pbnard go for 2 for 2 !  ;=)

Comment: @Diablo Change your col-lg by col-xs

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your solution on large screens or use col-md-x instead of col-lg-x